# jetback compose keep pushing my view in Box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

jetpack compose keep pushing ProgressIndicator when keyboard is opened, I do not want the keyboard to overlap anything at all

```
Box(
Modifier
.fillMaxSize()

)
 {
     BasicTextField()
     
        ProgressIndicator(
            isVisible = uiState.isLoading 
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val insets = LocalWindowInsets.current
    val imeBottom = with(LocalDensity.current) { insets.ime.bottom.toDp() }
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(bottom = imeBottom)) {
    }
```

using Insets for Jetpack Compose